# Caffeine Cache: How to update cache value without changing expire time

Tags: caching, caffeine-cache

I am using caffeine cache and looking for a way to update the value in cache without changing its expire time.

The scenario is that I am using cache for speed up data loading. A 5 seconds' delay of data changing is acceptable while I expect returns to be fast. Besides, I want these cache to expiry after 1 day of its first hit to avoid unnecessary memory use.

Thus, I want every cached keys lasts for one day but its value is updated every 5 second.

The `refreshAfterWrite` method seems to be close but its first returned value after refresh duration is still the old one. This is not ideal for me because the duration between two hits can be hours. In this case I still want a relatively new result (no more than 5 seconds).

So I am trying to manually updating each key.

Firstly I built a cache with 24 hours' expire time in this way:

```
cache = Caffeine.newBuilder()
    .expireAfterWrite(24, TimeUnit.HOURS)
    .build();
```

Then I wrote a scheduled task per 5 seconds which iterate keys in cache and do following:

```
cache.asMap().computeIfPresent(key, mapperFunction);
```

Then I checked the age of the key:

```
cache.policy().expireAfterWrite().get().ageOf(key)
```

However, the age is not growing as expected. I think the `computeIfPresent`  method is considered as a "write" so that the expiry time is also updated.

Is there a way to do the value update without change its expire time in caffeine?
Or any other approach for my scenario?

Answer (score 3):

A write is the creation or update of a mapping, so `expireAfterWrite` is not a good fit for you. Instead you can set a custom expiration policy that sets the initial duration and does nothing on a read or update. This is done using `expireAfter(Expiry)`, such as

```java
LoadingCache<Key, Graph> graphs = Caffeine.newBuilder()
    .expireAfter(new Expiry<Key, Graph>() {
      public long expireAfterCreate(Key key, Graph graph, long currentTime) {
        return TimeUnit.HOURS.toNanos(24);
      }
      public long expireAfterUpdate(Key key, Graph graph, 
          long currentTime, long currentDuration) {
        return currentDuration;
      }
      public long expireAfterRead(Key key, Graph graph,
          long currentTime, long currentDuration) {
        return currentDuration;
      }
    })
    .build(key -> createExpensiveGraph(key));
```

Comment: Direct quote from documentation on `expireAfter(Expiry)` found at https://github.com/ben-manes/caffeine/wiki/Eviction:
`expireAfter(Expiry): Expires entries after the variable duration has passed. This could be desirable if the expiration time of an entry is determined by an external resource.` This use case seems to fit what @Yoskyalogn was looking for.